# Combine user ratings from Amazon.co.uk & Amazon.com

Tags: webapp-rec, amazon, mashup

Does anyone know of a website (probably using Amazon's AWS web services) that will allow searching for a product (mostly books, so searching by ISBN is sufficient) and then displaying a *combined* view of the user ratings (the "star" rating from 1 to 5) along with the reviews from both Amazon.co.uk AND Amazon.com (and possibly other countries Amazon sites too) ?

Answer (score -1):

The Wish List browser add-ons can add items to Wish Lists in any country where we have a retail website. To change the default Wish List location in which items are added to please follow the instructions for each specific browser below.

**Firefox**: Click on **"Tools"** > click "**Add-ons"** > Find the Amazon Wish List Add-on, click **"Options"** > under **"Location"** set the default Wish List location to **"Amazon.co.uk"** (if it's not already). Click **"Save Settings"** if you made any changes you want to keep.

**Chrome**: Right click on the Amazon Wish List extension > click **"Options"** > under **"Location"** set the default Wish List location to **"Amazon.co.uk"** (if it's not already.) Click **"Save Settings"** if you made any changes you want to keep.

**Safari**: Click on the **"gear"** icon on the top right of your browser window > click **"Preferences"** > click "Extensions." Locate the Amazon Wish List Add-on > find **"Wish List Location"** > from here set the default Wish List location to **"Amazon.co.uk"** (if it's not already.)

Hope it helped you